# In SPA authentication with Auth0, how does Auth0 remember that I’m logged in on page refresh?

Tags: auth0

I set up a React application using Auth0 for authentication where it redirects users to the Universal Login Page and then back to the application upon a successful login. It is based off of [The Complete Guide to React User Authentication with Auth0](https://auth0.com/blog/complete-guide-to-react-user-authentication/?_ga=2.208332434.1025503579.1638338566-2034073745.1638338565&_gl=1*sxlbtr*rollup_ga*MjAzNDA3Mzc0NS4xNjM4MzM4NTY1*rollup_ga_F1G3E656YZ*MTYzODM3ODM3NC4zLjEuMTYzODM4MDA5OC4xOQ..).

Everything works, but something I’m not clear on is how Auth0 is able to fetch my token when I reload the page. How does it remember I am logged in? I was looking at the cookies and I only see `auth0.<CLIENT_ID_HERE>.is.authenticated` with a value of `true` or `false`, but nothing that uniquely identifies me.

I see `code` and `code_verifier` in the request payload of `POST /oauth/token` but I have no idea where that data is stored in the browser so it can be used on subsequent page reloads.

[image]

What’s also interesting is that if I open my demo app in an Incognito window, the session isn’t maintained between page reloads.

Comment: It is stored in cookies, depending on where you check the cookies you cannot see them because they are not for your domain but auth0

Comment: You're saying I can't see them in Chrome Dev Tools? I'm looking under Application > Storage > Cookies and I only see http://localhost:300 which is where my React app is running. If I can't see it in Chrome Dev Tools, how is it that the Auth0 library is able to read them and send them in the request payload to POST https://dev-lbsl3jjp.us.auth0.com/oauth/token?

Comment: Cookies are scoped to a domain, you do not see all the Facebook and Google cookies where you are looking either. You can certainly view ALL cookies in chrome somehow. The cookies are scoped to auth0 and are automatically sent alongside any auth0 targeting request.

Comment: Does the Auth0 JS / React library read those cookies? When I inspect the POST dev-lbsl3jjp.us.auth0.com/oauth/token request, it seems that information is in the request body. How is the library able to take those cookies and put it in the request body? I added a screenshot above.